# Switching from discord.js v12, how do I modify my code to Discord.js v13 syntax?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm attempting to create a giveaway bot for my discord server and as the title says, the code is pretty much written with a mix of djs v12 and djs v13. The bot currently turns on, but I'm getting a bunch of errors and I think it's originating from my `start.js` file. Does anyone have any idea how do I go about rectifying this?

The error is:

```
if (message.member.permission.has('MANAGE_MESSAGES') && !message.member.roles.cache.some((r) => r.id === config["Giveaway_Options"].giveawayManagerID)) {
                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'has')
```

My code in `start.js`:

```js
const ms = require('ms');
const config = require("../../config.json")

module.exports = {
    config: {
        name: "start",
        description: "Starts a giveaway.",
        usage: "[channel] [duration] [winners] [prize]",
        category: "Giveaways",
        accessableby: "Admins",
        aliases: [], // To add custom aliases just type ["alias1", "alias2"].
    },
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        if (config["Giveaway_Options"].giveawayManagerID) {
            if (!message.member.permission.has('MANAGE_MESSAGES') && !message.member.roles.cache.some((r) => r.id === config["Giveaway_Options"].giveawayManagerID)) {
                return message.channel.send(':boom: You need to have the \`MANAGE_MESSAGES\` permissions to start giveaways.');
            }
        } else {
            if (!message.member.permission.has('MANAGE_MESSAGES') && !message.member.roles.cache.some((r) => r.name === "Giveaways")) {
                return message.channel.send(':boom: You need to have the \`MANAGE_MESSAGES\` permissions to start giveaways.');
            }
        }

        let giveawayChannel = message.mentions.channels.first();
        if (!giveawayChannel) {
            return message.channel.send(':boom: Uh oh, I couldn\'t find that channel! Try again!');
        }

        let giveawayDuration = args[1];
        if (!giveawayDuration || isNaN(ms(giveawayDuration))) {
            return message.channel.send(':boom: Hm. you haven\'t provided a duration. Can you try again?');
        }

        let giveawayNumberWinners = args[2];
        if (isNaN(giveawayNumberWinners) || (parseInt(giveawayNumberWinners) <= 0)) {
            return message.channel.send(':boom: Uh... you haven\'t provided the amount of winners.');
        }

        let giveawayPrize = args.slice(3).join(' ');
        if (!giveawayPrize) {
            return message.channel.send(':boom: Oh, it seems like you didn\'t give me a valid prize!');
        }
        if (!config["Giveaway_Options"].showMention && config["Giveaway_Options"].giveawayRoleID && config["Giveaway_Options"].giveawayMention) {

            giveawayChannel.send(`<@&${config["Giveaway_Options"].giveawayRoleID}>`).then((msg) => msg.delete({ timeout: 1000 }))
            client.giveawaysManager.start(giveawayChannel, {
                time: ms(giveawayDuration),
                prize: giveawayPrize,
                winnerCount: parseInt(giveawayNumberWinners),
                hostedBy: config["Giveaway_Options"].hostedBy ? message.author : null,
                messages: {
                    giveaway: ":tada: **GIVEAWAY** :tada:",
                    giveawayEnded: ":tada: **GIVEAWAY ENDED** :tada:",
                    timeRemaining: "Time remaining: **{duration}**!",
                    inviteToParticipate: "React with  to participate!",
                    winMessage: "Congratulations, {winners}! You won the **{prize}**!",
                    embedFooter: "Giveaways",
                    noWinner: "Not enough entrants to determine a winner!",
                    hostedBy: "Hosted by: {user}",
                    winners: "winner(s)",
                    endedAt: "Ended at",
                    units: {
                        seconds: "seconds",
                        minutes: "minutes",
                        hours: "hours",
                        days: "days",
                        pluralS: false
                    }
                }
            });

        } else if (config["Giveaway_Options"].showMention && config["Giveaway_Options"].giveawayRoleID && config["Giveaway_Options"].giveawayMention) {

            client.giveawaysManager.start(giveawayChannel, {
                time: ms(giveawayDuration),
                prize: giveawayPrize,
                winnerCount: parseInt(giveawayNumberWinners),
                hostedBy: config["Giveaway_Options"].hostedBy ? message.author : null,
                messages: {
                    giveaway: (config["Giveaway_Options"].showMention ? `<@&${config["Giveaway_Options"].giveawayRoleID}>\n\n` : "") + ":tada: **GIVEAWAY** :tada:",
                    giveawayEnded: (config["Giveaway_Options"].showMention ? `<@&${config["Giveaway_Options"].giveawayRoleID}>\n\n` : "") + ":tada: **GIVEAWAY ENDED** :tada:",
                    timeRemaining: "Time remaining: **{duration}**!",
                    inviteToParticipate: "React with  to participate!",
                    winMessage: "Congratulations, {winners}! You won the **{prize}**!",
                    embedFooter: "Giveaways",
                    noWinner: "Not enough entrants to determine a winner!",
                    hostedBy: "Hosted by: {user}",
                    winners: "winner(s)",
                    endedAt: "Ended at",
                    units: {
                        seconds: "seconds",
                        minutes: "minutes",
                        hours: "hours",
                        days: "days",
                        pluralS: false
                    }
                }
            });

        } else if (!config["Giveaway_Options"].showMention && !config["Giveaway_Options"].giveawayRoleID && config["Giveaway_Options"].giveawayMention) {
            giveawayChannel.send(`@everyone`).then((msg) => msg.delete({ timeout: 1000 }))
            client.giveawaysManager.start(giveawayChannel, {
                time: ms(giveawayDuration),
                prize: giveawayPrize,
                winnerCount: parseInt(giveawayNumberWinners),
                hostedBy: config["Giveaway_Options"].hostedBy ? message.author : null,
                messages: {
                    giveaway: ":tada: **GIVEAWAY** :tada:",
                    giveawayEnded: ":tada: **GIVEAWAY ENDED** :tada:",
                    timeRemaining: "Time remaining: **{duration}**!",
                    inviteToParticipate: "React with  to participate!",
                    winMessage: "Congratulations, {winners}! You won the **{prize}**!",
                    embedFooter: "Giveaways",
                    noWinner: "Not enough entrants to determine a winner!",
                    hostedBy: "Hosted by: {user}",
                    winners: "winner(s)",
                    endedAt: "Ended at",
                    units: {
                        seconds: "seconds",
                        minutes: "minutes",
                        hours: "hours",
                        days: "days",
                        pluralS: false
                    }
                }
            });

        } else if (config["Giveaway_Options"].showMention && !config["Giveaway_Options"].giveawayRoleID && config["Giveaway_Options"].giveawayMention) {
            client.giveawaysManager.start(giveawayChannel, {
                time: ms(giveawayDuration),
                prize: giveawayPrize,
                winnerCount: parseInt(giveawayNumberWinners),
                hostedBy: config["Giveaway_Options"].hostedBy ? message.author : null,
                messages: {
                    giveaway: (config["Giveaway_Options"].showMention ? `@everyone\n\n` : "") + ":tada: **GIVEAWAY** :tada:",
                    giveawayEnded: (config["Giveaway_Options"].showMention ? `@everyone\n\n` : "") + ":tada: **GIVEAWAY ENDED** :tada:",
                    timeRemaining: "Time remaining: **{duration}**!",
                    inviteToParticipate: "React with  to participate!",
                    winMessage: "Congratulations, {winners}! You won the **{prize}**!",
                    embedFooter: "Giveaways",
                    noWinner: "Not enough entrants to determine a winner!",
                    hostedBy: "Hosted by: {user}",
                    winners: "winner(s)",
                    endedAt: "Ended at",
                    units: {
                        seconds: "seconds",
                        minutes: "minutes",
                        hours: "hours",
                        days: "days",
                        pluralS: false
                    }
                }
            });
        } else if (!config["Giveaway_Options"].giveawayMention) {
            client.giveawaysManager.start(giveawayChannel, {
                time: ms(giveawayDuration),
                prize: giveawayPrize,
                winnerCount: parseInt(giveawayNumberWinners),
                hostedBy: config["Giveaway_Options"].hostedBy ? message.author : null,
                messages: {
                    giveaway: ":tada: **GIVEAWAY** :tada:",
                    giveawayEnded: ":tada: **GIVEAWAY ENDED** :tada:",
                    timeRemaining: "Time remaining: **{duration}**!",
                    inviteToParticipate: "React with  to participate!",
                    winMessage: "Congratulations, {winners}! You won the **{prize}**!",
                    embedFooter: "Giveaways",
                    noWinner: "Not enough entrants to determine a winner!",
                    hostedBy: "Hosted by: {user}",
                    winners: "winner(s)",
                    endedAt: "Ended at",
                    units: {
                        seconds: "seconds",
                        minutes: "minutes",
                        hours: "hours",
                        days: "days",
                        pluralS: false
                    }
                }
            });
        }


        message.channel.send(`:tada: Done! The giveaway for the \`${giveawayPrize}\` is starting in ${giveawayChannel}!`);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's [`message.member.permissions.has()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=has), plural.

Comment: oh shoot okay, got it, now I'm having another error, the bot now turns on and sends the message that the giveaway is starting but I'm getting an error "The message event is deprecated. Use messageCreate instead but not showing from where it's originating from so I assume it's within my start.js

Comment: It's not an error but a warning, `client.on('message', ` should be `client.on('messageCreate', `

Comment: the only time I use the "client.on" is in my event.js where it's written as "client.on(eName, evt.bind(null, client));"

Comment: Without seeing your code/file structure, I think you probably have a `message.js` file. You can rename it to `messageCreate.js`.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you typed it wrong, which is not a problem at all.
simply change it to this...

```
if (!message.member.permissions.has('MANAGE_MESSAGES')
```

For the error relating to the `message` event, it has changed to `messageCreate` in v13.

So if you have a file named `message.js` or something in that nature, or if you have it in your `index.js`/`main.js`, all you would need to do is this

v12

```
client.on('message', () => {});
```

v13

```
client.on('messageCreate', () => {});
```

just change it from `message` to `messageCreate` as seen above.

Comment: This is my current message.js module.exports = async (client, message) => {
    if (message.author.bot || message.channel.type === "dm") return;

    let args = message.content.slice(config["Bot_Info"].prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    let cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();